# Rails Production Web Server on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, deployment, production-environment, production

I'm almost finished with the development of my first ruby on rails app. I am using windows for development. Now i want to deploy my app (most likely on iPage web hosting). the procedure described in Agile Web dev... appear to only work on MAC OS X (with passenger, etc) and didn't have much luck googling.

My questions are:

1- Is there a good and easy to follow tutorial/book/etc on how to set up local production server on windows (e.g. using apache and mysql (Possibly WAMP)) and porting it to a remote host?

2- can the book "Deploying Rails Applications: A Step-by-Step Guide" help me?

3- Would it worth the effort that i install VMware,Ubunto (or another Unix/Linux based OS) and  do the production there?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar situation where we had to decide on Rails app deployment to a Windows server rather than to a Linux one. I did some research but never tried out anything since fortunately we decided to stick with a Linux server. I was not particularly happy with what I found but here it is in case it helps:

[Deployment to Windows using Capistrano based gem](http://github.com/SciMed/capistrano-windows-server)

[Articles on other deployment options to Windows](http://napcs.com/howto/rails/deploy/)

Comment: IT's probably too late now, but just use Heroku! super easy to deploy and they gave enough DB for free to test